# Printing from label printer using Crystal Report in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am creating an desktop application for printing label from label printer. Can anyone guide me how to print from label printer using crystal report approach. I am new to this topic and have no idea.

I would appreciate if anyone provide me some sample program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of label printer that you have.

If you use Crystal Report, then your application will be printer agnostic, it wouldn't care which type of printer you use. Also you will not be able to use some features that you label printer might have like, controllable label cutting.

Label printers usually have API. So you would normally design a label in a template designer, that is normally supplied with your printer. Then you would call API providing the file path to the template and filling the data that template requires.